# Angular: Module and feature directory naming conventions

Tags: angularjs, module, naming-conventions

I'm working on a large scale site that's been in production for 5 years.

What's working well:

- Organizing code by features (much better than by controllers etc.)
- Organizing code by modules (at a higher level to features).

We have a clear hierarchy in the system which leads to submodules. And then more submodules. And then some more. Currently it's 4 or 5 levels deep. And actually this works well too.

Within a module folder, we would have:

- /anotherModule
- /directives
- /featureA
- /featureB
- /layout
- /moduleX
- /thisModule
- /thisIsAFeature
- routes.js

This was OK but wasn't great. The list of directories became too large to easily navigate and there was nothing making it clear that 'layout' wasn't a submodule.

So we grouped together modules and features into their own directories. We now have:

- /features
- /layout
- /modules
- /services
- routes.js

And this works better. But, I'm fed up of navigating into /modules/private-site/modules/projects/modules/results/modules/...

So, my plan is to instead prefix module directories with a hyphen (-) and feature directories with an underscore, e.g.:

- -anotherModule
- -moduleX
- -thisModule
- _featureA
- _featureB
- _thisIsAFeature
- directives
- layout
- routes.js

Now, this works *great*. But, I don't like to go against convention. I haven't seen a good convention here, so would welcome any recommendations on how best to name these directories *or* how best to tackle the issues that led to the current situation.

Comment: Some immediate thoughts on my own suggestion: (i) Having # and _ at the start of directory names might cause issues in some environments? This wouldn't be an issue for our users as the modules and features would all be built into a single file pre-release. (ii) I sometimes use the underscore prefix to identify a private or legacy directory. Not sure if this is common but might want to pick a different prefix as a result.

Comment: What is the total number of modules/features you have? It should be quite big system if you have 4-5 levels of hierarchy. Unfortunately the answer heavily depends on the nature of your system, size of the team and so on.

Comment: Currently there is no more than 5 features or submodules in any module, though this is likely to grow in a few places. Generally I'm happy with the structure (it logically makes sense and would be easy to navigate was it not for the 'modules' subdirs interrupting your line of thought)

Comment: I'm a bit confused with structure that has submodules and features on the same level. It should be totally different by nature and currently looks like a file system where modules=folders and features=files. From my point of view, you should try to remove "submodules" at all. Probably you will be able to structure it as, for example, AREA=>Module=>Feature. You probably have some common stuff that you can put in Common folder at Module level

Comment: @PavelKutakov : Example: I have an area of the site for managing survey responses. With this area, I have features for listing participants and responses, viewing an activity feed etc. I also have a submodule for viewing a specific participant.  Both the features and submodule are represented by directories. The submodule differs to the features in that I define it as a module and specify the associated routes in that directory. Your suggestion is to have a smaller hierarchy and that would make sense.. if we had a smaller site :).

Comment: Edited original question to use a hyphen prefix for module names. It ain't pretty, but works (unlike a hash- or dot-prefix)

Comment: Maybe you can generalize routes somehow to reduce number of specific stuff for submodule? Maybe something can be moved to base controller and common views? Anyway, as for structure you propose in your post, I can offer to use underscore for submodule name and don't use anything for the rest - this will put your modules on the top of the list and visually divide them. Or features can also have "F_" prefix, they will be visually different from "layout" and other folders.